# Dispose of static/singleton in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks, timer, singleton

I am trying to create a cross platform .NET library (here used in Unity) in which I need a static function.
So, as an example, the main function would be used like so: `MyLib.AddCallback(Action callback)`.
I then use a static `System.Timers.Timer` with `AutoReset = true` in order to run that callback on a regular basis. (This is just an example)

There is the problem. If I test my library in Unity, bind the callback to `Debug.Log` and hit Play, the timer starts as intended, therefore logging messages, but does not stop when leaving Play Mode, causing memory leaks (sometimes logging the `OutOfMemoryException`).

I see how this could make sense, as the general process of Unity is still running. However, and obviously, I do not want that. I want to stop running the callback and properly dispose of my `Timer` when the app stops. And I do not know how to do such thing.

I tried to create a singleton instead, put my `Timer` as an instance property and implement the `IDisposable` interface in my singleton class. This didn't solve my issue, as the singleton is never disposed.

**One last thing.** I cannot rely on a `GameObject` to call my Dispose or my Update methods (instead of a timer) simply because I am not targeting exclusively Unity.

Anyone has an idea of how I should manage that?

Thank you very much

### Edit

Just found [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/c-timer-is-still-running-on-application-close.39570/) that describes exactly my problem. Still not solved...

Comment: Why not just run your callback with InvokeRepeating(); or a co-routine? That should stop when playmode stops.

Comment: Because that means relying on a gameobject to invoke my callback. That implies adding a GameObject with DontDestroyOnLoad but my library needs to be cross platform (not only for Unity) so, can't really rely on that...

Comment: Stop trying to change your question into something else. If your problem is not Unity related then don't tag Unity. It clearly says *"If I test my library in Unity, bind the callback to Debug.Log and hit Play, the timer starts as intended, therefore logging messages, but does not stop when leaving Play Mode, causing memory leaks (sometimes logging the OutOfMemoryException)."* so that's what the first part of my answer addressed. That problem should be solved by now.

Comment: I said from the beginning that I cannot rely on a GameObject. I realised my question was not clear. I edited it to avoid further confusion. I thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Timer is running in another Thread.

You can stop and dispose the timer in the `OnDisable` function which is called when you stop the Editor.

```
public class TimerTest: MonoBehaviour
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    void OnDisable()
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

---

Usually, you should do this with a coroutine in Unity.

Example of a 1 second timer:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(startTimer(1));
}

IEnumerator startTimer(float time)
{
    while (true)
    {
        //Wait for x seconds
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

        //Invoke function
        doSomthing();
    }

}

void doSomthing()
{

}
```

---

If you need to see the microseconds in the timer or the timer value is so small  then use `Time.deltaTime`.

Comment: I edited my question to make that clearer. My library is supposed to be cross-platform, so I cannot rely on a GameObject to call a function regularly. That's why I decided to use a Timer in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two cents after you rephrased your question.

Not sure if you can completely avoid to add something to Unity's lifecycle.

A solution could be that you make a "OnExit()" function in your library which can then be called different places depending which framework you work in.

In Unity, you could call it in the OnDisable() lifecycle method.

In another framework you could place it somewhere else which you know will be called upon the application quitting.

For a reference to see which lifecycle methods exist in Unity, look at the link below.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

If you let us know where else you would consider using your library, that could help people elaborate on possibilities more.